# How much columns can we add in Data table C#

Tags: datatable, ado.net

I have been working in reading columns from excel sheet through Data table in C#. I am facing issue while adding extra columns after 254. It is not getting dat from excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

the limit comes from the connection provider reading the columns from the xl spreadsheet so it is not a limit on the datacolumns itself of the datatable object. Instead, try to use the Range query operator to obtain a range of columns and keep doing so until no more columns are to be read and append it to the datatable/columns

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar thread:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cf21f1be-d6e8-4ed9-b977-d6876bf0cf06/import-data-from-excel-file-into-a-datatable-column-limit?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

we should use "Range" to resolve the issue as per the above thread.I am pasting the marked answer from the above thread:

255 is the column limit for provider i guess. Anyway try to use 'Range" in select command and see what is happening.

string sql = "select * from [Foglio1$A1:BP1200]"; // apply range to the query

Hope this helps.

P.S: all credit goes to  "Alex Liang"